# Does the video-game industry have good salaries?

Tags: salary

I know that it depends on the job position, location, experience and so but what do you think guys?

For example, the best countries to find good companies are USA, Canada, England, Scotland, Netherlands, France, Germany, Sweden and Japan.

Which could be the salary for a gameplay programmer who just graduated for college
and find a job in a small company?

Comment: Overall salaries are OK. Per-hour is terrible.

Comment: Depends on the company, on your skills, on whether you ate or aren't counting the gamble of whether the game succeeds in the marketplace and you get your bonus...

Comment: Question is too vague  to be answerable. Aside from that, we are not a salary research service. Do your own research.

Answer (score 6):

In general salaries for most are below average and working hours are terrible. Remember every new graduate wants to work in games so the rules of the market apply.

Some jobs for specialists are very well paid. But although I might pay an X-box specialist $1K/day to fix a problem in my game for a few weeks, they are going to get no more work when I need a PS4 expert the next month.

Comment: Matches my experience. Expert console devs can certainly demand good money, but it's a long grind for low pay to develop that expertise.